# asp.net core target framework 4.6.1 publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have asp.net core application that targets framework 4.6.1, When I try to publish, it generates .exe file instead of .dll and I can not publish it on iis. it working correctly when I run generated .exe and open http://localhost:5000  from browser it works good, but I want to host it on iis.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at target library compiler option.

The /target:library option causes the compiler to create a dynamic-link library (DLL) rather than an executable file (EXE).

When specified at the command line, all files up to the next /out or /target:module option are used to create the .dll file.

Example:

```
csc /target:library in.cs
```

Compile in.cs, creating in.dll

To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment open the project's **Properties** page and modify the **Output** type property to **Class Library**

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/target-library-compiler-option)

Comment: While this might answer the question, it is better to put the relevant details here, since links might become invalid over time. It will also help you to score points ;-)